# Introducir datos por fecha a java desde mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jtable, jdatechooser

tengo una duda sobre como ingresar datos a un `Jtable` cuando la fecha de mi `JDateChooser` sea igual a la que tengo en mi tabla de [phpmyadmin](/questions/tagged/phpmyadmin). Tengo el siguiente codigo:
donde "pedidos" es donde tengo el `JFrame` con el `JTable` y el `JDateChooser` y `getBuscarfecha` es como he llamado a mi `JDateChooser`.

```
  public void ingresarDatos(){
  Connection miConexion=null;
    Statement st;
    
    Date fecha=pedidos.getBuscarfecha().getDate();
   
    ResultSet rs=BaseDatosProductos.dameTabla2("SELECT `Fecha`, `numPedido`, `Total`, `Productos` FROM `pedidos`"
            + " WHERE Fecha='"+fecha+"' ");
    try {
        miConexion=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/productos_juanjo", 
                "root", "quepasachavales3");
        st=miConexion.createStatement();
        while(rs.next()){
            
        tabla.addRow(new Object[]{rs.getDate("Fecha"), rs.getInt("numPedido"),
            rs.getDouble("Total"),rs.getString("Productos")});
        
        }
        pedidos.getTablaPedidos().setModel(tabla);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Pedidos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 
}
```

Comment: ¿Cual es exactamente el problema?

Comment: PD: Ojo phpMyAdmin no es una bbdd.

Comment: que cuando intento buscar por fecha no me sale los datos referentes a esa fecha y la tabla se queda en blanco

Comment: Es que estas comparando mal en la query. El objeto fecha vas a tener que convertirlo a un formato entendible por la BBDD. Para ello usa SimpleDateFormat. Ejemplo de como usarlo -> http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=SimpleDateFormat

Comment: Que yo sepa, phpMyAdmin no tiene tablas ni puede enviar nada.

Comment: De casualidad te refieres a la clase JDateChooser de la librería [tag:jcalendar]?